# la interfaz de Raspberry no enciende (solo consola), por haber editado mal "/etc/fstab"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

El problema comenzó porque mientras encendía la raspberry pi esta pedía ingresar `ctrl+D` para algo de mantenimiento seguía [la respuesta de un foro](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=61821), tal vez lo hice mal.

El asunto es que puse 0 a todas las líneas y ahora cuando la enciendo solo me sale la consola, tratando de editar con `sudo nano /etc/fstab` no me deja ya que está solo en modo de lectura.

He intentado varias respuestas y no he dado con la solución:
[r1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179855/device-already-mounted-or-resource-is-busy)
[r2](https://barrabinbarrabash.com/raspberry-pi-no-arranca-despues-de-editar-el-fstab/)
[r3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95883/rpi-wont-boot-after-editing-fstab)

en resumen:
`sudo mount -n -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`
y cambiando `init = /bin/bash` en la sdCard del cmdline.txt
Lo que responde es que ya está montada u ocupada, mientras al intentar editar con nano dice que solo permite lectura.

¿Cómo logro editar de nuevo `fstab` para poder ponerla como antes de liarla?

Comment: ¿Has probado de quitar la sdCard del raspberry y ponerla en un lector de otro pc o portátil y acceder a el?

Comment: @masterguru sí pero solo tengo windows como que la sdCard está particionada y me sale solo una de 60MB (la sdCard es de 16GB) y sale otra inaccesible por formato desconocido. Intenté en virtualbox con linux-ubuntu pero no me reconoce la sdCard en el virtualbox.

Comment: ¿y si te creas un usb/cd de arranque de ubuntu (el de la instalacion serviria supongo) y arrancas esa maquina con el?  Con un poco de suerte reconocera el lector y podras ver la sdcard

Comment: @masterguru Sí tocó en linux externo, lo hice en virtualbox, había que instalar `VM VirtualBox Extension Pack` y  activar lectura sdcard con `vboxmanage modifyvm "vmname" --usbcardreader on` [fuente](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97669), con `sudo gedit [path]`

Comment: O sea, que dando un rodeo pero ya lo has conseguido, verdad?  Me alegro pues :-)

Comment: @masterguru bueno, aún tengo que ingresar `Ctrl+D` cada vez que la enciendo que era el problema inicial, he quedado donde empecé. Aunque la pregunta si queda resuelta. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo del Control+D creo que es porque no tiene establecido el arranque correctamente creo... mira de hacer otra pregunta pegando tu fstab a ver si lo vemos